# Can submit buttons in Ajax forms have their name attribute set?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax

i have the following form

```
<form action="ManageLink" method="post">
    <input name="artistName" type="text"/>
    <input name="songName" type="text"/>
    <input name="url" type="text"/>
    <input name="action" id="save" type="submit" value="Save"/>
    <input name="action" id="delete" type="submit" value="Delete"/>
</form>
```

with this signature for the action method

```
public JavaScriptResult ManageLink(string artistName, string songName, string url, string action)
```

I'm naming the submit buttons so that I can know which one was clicked, and act accordingly.

I'm trying to turn this into an ajax form as shown below

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("ManageLink", new AjaxOptions()))
   { %>
        <input name="artistName" type="text"/>
        <input name="songName" type="text"/>
        <input name="url" type="text"/>

        <input name="action" type="submit" value="Save"/>
        <input name="action" type="submit" value="Delete"/>
<% } %>
```

however i get an error in the MicrosoftAjax.js code.

If i remove the name="action" property then i dont get the error, but then I'm not able to tell which button was clicked.

Is there something I've got wrong in the code above?
Or is there a better approach that i can use to detect which button was clicked?

Comment: What happens if you change "name" to "ID"? And what exactly is the error message you get in the MicrosoftAjax.js code?

Comment: Changing name to ID gives the same error, Which is this: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method For this line: Sys.Net.WebRequest._resolveUrl=function(b,a){if(b&&b.indexOf("://")!==-1). b is a list of input tags

Comment: What doctype are you using for HTML? Some doctypes don't allow both name and id to be set.

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/169871-how-set-name-button-javascript

Comment: I spoke too soon. I changed names of all submit buttons this time and I didnt get the error.

but then I'm not sure how to access the submit button's value in the ActionMethod. I was using the name "action" to group the submit buttons as you can see in the ActionMethod's signature i posted. This grouping i'm assuming is what is causing the error, since a list is being passed where a list is not expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input name="save" type="submit" value="Save" />
<input name="delete" type="submit" value="Delete" />
```

and in your action:

```
public ActionResult ManageLink(string artistName, string songName, string url)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["save"]))
    {
        // Save was clicked
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["delete"]))
    {
        // Delete was clicked
    }
    return View();
}
```

or if you prefer action arguments:

```
public ActionResult ManageLink(string artistName, string songName, string url, string save, string delete)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(save))
    {
        // Save was clicked
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(delete))
    {
        // Delete was clicked
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, used your solution and added some code from here
http://blog.ashmind.com/2010/03/15/multiple-submit-buttons-with-asp-net-mvc-final-solution/ to add an action method per submit button